# PUT Method Fails to Update Array of Multiple Images (ImgBB API)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

Encountering a hiccup with the PUT method in my web app. While other data fields update fine, the array of multiple images remains unchanged. Utilizing the ImgBB API for image hosting. All other CRUD operations (POST, DELETE, GET) work flawlessly, but the PUT method struggles only with multiple images. Seeking advice to resolve this issue. Thanks!

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvqGR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otR0g.png)

I attempted to update the array of multiple images using the PUT method in my web application. I ensured that the code for handling image uploads and updating the database was correctly implemented.

Comment: Please do NOT put code here into images - ever.  It can't be copied into answers, can't be easily read on a phone, is annoying to read on a desktop, etc...  In fact, it's very difficult to make an answer when you can't copy code into the answer - so this discourages people from both reading the code and from making an answer.  All code in your question should be pasted directly into the question and formatted properly as code.  You can use the "edit" link below your question to fix it.